# AlertDialogPro with custom Typeface

Tags: android, alertdialogpro

I'm trying to set a custom typeface to a dialog built using  [AlertDialogPro](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro) but get a NPE when trying to retrieve the dialog Button using `dialog.getButton(int)`. And how can I set the typeface for the message and title of the dialog?

```
AlertDialogPro.Builder builder = new AlertDialogPro.Builder(this);
   builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_body))
   .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          // Do stuff
      }
});

AlertDialogPro dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTypeface(customTf));
dialog.show();
```

Log:

```
03-02 16:30:22.982: E/AndroidRuntime(15596): 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android
.widget.Button.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null
object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing two things:

1. Moved the getButton() to after dialog.show()
2. Used findViewById() to retrieve the message textview

Code:

```
AlertDialogPro.Builder builder = new AlertDialogPro.Builder(this);
   builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_body))
   .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          // Do stuff
      }
});

AlertDialogPro dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTypeface(customTf));
((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.adp_message)).setTypeface(customTf);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only access dialog buttons (via `dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)`) after call `dialog.show()`.

Comment: Yea, figured that one out the hard way:)

Answer (score 0):

Call this method:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(int textId,final OnClickListener listener)
```

before creating the dialog